# Add card view on button click

Tags: android, youtube

I want to implement the new cardview option with android support v7. I already compiled the libraries for both cardview and Recycler View. My plan is for somebody to click a button and then a cardview will show up in a linear layout similar to what happens in the beginning of this youtube video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U105suLp8TQ) sadly the video doesn't use eclipse or android studio so I can't completely follow the tutorial. Anybody know how to create a gridview when a button is pressed. If you are confused on what I am saying please watch the first 3 min of the youtube link. That is what I am trying to do. Thanks!